# Setting and passing different params with Angular Provider ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, cucumber, rxjs, karma-runner

In my Angular 2 component tests, I was using the following to pass a parameter:

```
providers: [
    { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {'params': Observable.from([{'id': 5}])} }
]
```

However, in my step definitions, I would like to be able to pass different values for id parameter to be able to test different scenarios for different ids. I read somewhere, that using Subject is more suitable for this instead of using Observable.

Hence, I changed the approach to:

```
public static initializeComponent(callback: cucumber.IStepCallback): void {
let params = new Subject<Params>();
params.next([{'id': 5}]);

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
    { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {'params': params }}
    ]
});
```

hoping that in each of my step definitions, I can change the value of 'id' parameter' using:

params.next([{'id':6}]);
params.next([{'id': 7}]);

etc.

Is my approach correct? If yes, it doesnt work, even the first time when I set id as 5. Either there is a problem in the approach, or possibly I am setting the 
params.next incorrectly? Or there is some other issue? I am not very familiar with this stuff, and trying it for the first time, so I am not sure what is wrong. Any inputs?

Comment: Can you show your component body? Where do you listen ActivatedRoute?

Comment: I added an update above showing the code on component side and also the fact that it worked fine with Observable. Only with Subject, it does not work

Comment: Did you check docs? I answered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is case in docs. It is describing what you need peerfectly. https://angular.io/guide/testing#create-an-observable-test-double

Did you try it? If yes  can you please explain what problem do you have with that case.

What is the difference between your solution and guide solution? Well, guide has example with BehaviourSubject, not because of subject. Difference is in Subject you get only new emmitted values, but in BehaviourSubject you also get current value immediately.

Comment: From the document you sent, I am not able to make out what mistake I am making in the code above using the Subject to pass param. With the first Observable approach I used, it enters the constructor in my component. But, with the subject approach I took, it does not enter the constructor

Comment: I fixed the link. I was texting from phone so I missclicked. I also will update a bit my answer.

Comment: I changed to use BehaviorSubject, but still have an issue that I added in my original question under Update 2***. Do you have any pointers on that?

Comment: Can you provide full code? What is component. How you provide mock test data. Why you expect it should he called. Hard to help without that code.

Comment: I updated with some additional code that I could put here. Let me know if that clears things bit more?

Comment: What is code of the component? How you use data service in it? Why you expect method should be called?